Conflicting information about HTML checkbox's "checked" attribute
According to this MDN article, the checked attribute of a checkbox only indicates whether a checkbox is ticked by default, and not its current state.
However, very basic testing reveals it does reflect the checkbox's current state :
<input type="checkbox" id="test">
<button type="button" onclick="console.log(document.querySelector('#test').checked);">Test</button>

Is the MDN article wrong, or are browsers simply not conforming with the specification here ?

yea the article is wrong "checked — Whether the control is checked
" see specification

The MDN article is correct. Browsers are correct too. The discrepancy is explained by the fact that an HTML checkbox has both a checked content attribute and a checked JavaScript property, which are related but distinct. The article discusses the former, whereas your code uses the latter.
The checked content attribute corresponds to the actual checked, checked="", or checked="checked" attribute, if any, in the HTML markup of the <input> element. You can get the attribute’s value by calling the Element.getAttribute method:


<input type="checkbox" id="test" checked="checked">
<button type="button" onclick="console.log(document.querySelector('#test').getAttribute('checked') ?? 'null');">Log Attribute</button>



In the snippet above, the checkbox is checked by default, and the button will log the string "checked" regardless of whether you toggle the checkbox on or off.
In contrast, as you’ve observed, the checked JavaScript property reflects the current state of the checkbox:


<input type="checkbox" id="test" checked="checked">
<button type="button" onclick="console.log(document.querySelector('#test').checked);">Log Property</button>




Thank you ! I had no idea those things were separate, my main language is C x)

The article clarifies that the HTMLInputElement's checked value does update with state, which you can read more about here.
With that said, I have no idea how to explain the difference between these concepts, and am not sure I even understand it myself. Any more clarity is welcome!
